# Using while loop to seperate string

Tags: java

I am having trouble with some String methods. In the code below a user enters their full name and the code separates it into first and last name.

```
while(x < name.length())
    {
      if(name.charAt(x) == ' ')
      {
        firstName = name.substring(0, x);
        familyName = name.substring(x + 1, name.length());
        x = name.length();
      }
      ++x;
    }
```

I am having trouble understanding what the requirement of the while loop is, as I read it, x is assigned to the name.length in the if statement which would set x == name.length() meaning the loop would only run once???

Can someone please help me break this down?

Comment: How about `String names[]= name.split(" ")` ? You are looking for space character by traversing the name character by character.

Comment: The loop only runs once if the first character is a space, this is bad programming. The `x = name.length()` should be replaced with a `break` to make things more clear as that is essentially what it is acting as

Comment: This is code given to me as course material, the break does make more sense to me, does the if statement test one char at a time?

Comment: yes the `charAt` function only looks at one character

Comment: May be you can use indexOf() to get the index of space and then the rest you know..

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you must be useing while code,maybe you can use name.split(" ") if you can sure that name ,useing " "separates first and last name,you can easy to separates it into first and last name.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `x` to `name.length()` turns `while` condition `x < name.length()` to `false`, so it definitely does the trick: you will break out of the loop.

However, the code does not make clear the purpose of setting `x` to `name.length()`: even experienced coders would take a few seconds to figure out what you are trying to do. A better approach is to use `break` statement, which is specifically designed for ending the loop:

```
if(name.charAt(x) == ' ')
{
    firstName = name.substring(0, x);
    familyName = name.substring(x + 1, name.length());
    break;
}
```

Note that your code has two additional problems:

- If the input does not contain a space, `firstName` and `familyName` remain unset, and
- If the input contains a space as the last character, the code would throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you the break does make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the breakdown of the logic:**

This would loop from `x = 0` (assuming this is what it was initialized to) up to the length of the `name` string.

```
while(x < name.length())
```

This portion is entered upon finding the first `space` character.

```
if(name.charAt(x) == ' ')
```

This assigns the `firstName` and the `familyName`. `firstName` is from start of the `name` string to the character before the first `space`, `familyName` is from first character after `space` to the end of the `name` string. E.g. for `Jane Doe`, `firstName` is set to Jane and `familyName` is set to Doe.

```
firstName = name.substring(0, x);
familyName = name.substring(x + 1, name.length());
```

After the assignment, `x` is set to a condition which would not execute the `while` loop the next time.

```
x = name.length();
```

If a `space` was not encountered, `x` is incremented so that the next character in the `name` string can be evaluated.

```
++x;
```

A better way to do this is to write a `break` statement instead of setting `x = name.length()`. This will exit the `while` loop after the first `space` character is found and after the `firstName` and `familyName` name are set.

```
if(name.charAt(x) == ' ') {
  firstName = name.substring(0, x);
  familyName = name.substring(x + 1, name.length());
  break;
}
++x;
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, I was getting confused thinking that the code block in the if statement was being run each time, of course it doesn’t!